# Z3C New Firmware?

Tags: updates, 5.0-lollipop, 5.1-lollipop, sony-xperia-z3

I just got a message from Sony saying new firmware is available for my Z3C (23.1.A.0.726). Anybody else get this? Anyone know what's in the update? The PC companion software doesn't give any details. Is this an update to 5.1? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's 5.0.2. Probably some bug fixes only.

Comment: USA. The Sony website doesn't list it yet, but PC Companion has it.

Comment: You can check all firmwares (or even download them before OTA comes) using [XperiFirm](http://forum.xda-developers.com/crossdevice-dev/sony/pc-xperifirm-xperia-firmware-downloader-t2834142)

Comment: I have access, just curious as to what is in the update.

Comment: Could you add any references about this? Or is it based on your experience?

Comment: Confirmed 5.0.2 http://forum.xda-developers.com/z3-compact/general/23-1-0-726-rolling-t3076962/page3